# Change the position of the curves in a graph in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I have the following code to plot 4 text files in latex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[tick pos=left,name=plot, xlabel={Distance $\mu$m},ylabel={Contrast},
                xmin=300,xmax=500,ymin=750,ymax=950]
                % Indifference curves
                \addplot[coordinate style/.from={0},smooth = 6,color = black] table{./1L 4.txt};
                \addplot[color = red] table{./2L 4.txt};
                \addplot[color = green] table{./3L 4.txt};
                \addplot[color = blue] table{./4L 4.txt};
\end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

After compiling, the graph looks like 1 shown in the image below. However, I want to make the graph look like the 2 shown in the image below.
[image]

Comment: This question does not really make sense to me. The appearance of your plot is based on your data, on a linear scale the plot will look like the one on the left side. Or are you just talking about the styling? (the difference in x- and ylabels suggests that)
What are you unhappy about? It looks to me that the scaling of the screenshots is slightly different, other than that the plots look pretty similar, IMO.

Comment: As you can see in 1 the 4 curves are merged over one another. I want to separate them like in 2. Basically, I want to create an offset in the y-axis to show the 4 curves without merging.

Comment: Well, then my first point in my previous comment is applicable. The data governs how the plot looks, otherwise the plot is just wrong. For the graphs to be comparable, they have to belong to the same axis scaling.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\begin{filecontents}{1L 4.txt}
300 760
350 770
370 850
390 770
410 840
430 770
500 760
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
tick pos=left,
xlabel={Distance $\mu$m}, ylabel={Contrast},
xmin=300, xmax=500,
ymin=750, ymax=950, 
smooth, thick,
ytick=\empty,
]
\addplot[black] table {./1L 4.txt};
\addplot[red]   table[y expr={\thisrowno{1}+20}] {./1L 4.txt};
\addplot[green] table[y expr={\thisrowno{1}+40}] {./1L 4.txt};
\addplot[blue]  table[y expr={\thisrowno{1}+60}] {./1L 4.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graphs shifted up]

Comment: Thank you for the comments.